# How to keep Array order when doing a foreach loop in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

The order of my array always changes when i do a foreach loop. How can I keep the order of the array.

```
var array1 = [{id:1, name:'foo'},{id:2, name:'bar'},{id:3, name:'lol'}]
```

After i do a foreach and output it to a new array, the order sometimes changes

```
var array2 = [];

angular.forEach(array1, function(post) {
  //for brevity i'll just keep it simple
   var sample = {id:post.id, name:post.name};
   array2.push(sample);
});
```

---

```
//OUTPUT
var array2 = [{id:3, name:'lol'},{id:1, name:'foo'},{id:2, name:'bar'}]
```

My question is how can i iterate without changing the order.

Comment: What do you mean the array changes when you do a foreach loop? Are you getting the array from a web service?

Comment: yes im getting it from an ajax response but order is ALWAYS the same it just gets messed up after the foreach loop

Comment: @JLRishe i added the code

Comment: @e_mam106 If `array1` is actually an array, then this should not be happening. Can you show us what the actual JSON response of your service looks like?

Comment: Doing it in the console without using angular's version of `forEach` seems to work fine. Is there a specific reason why you're using angular's over the typical one?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over an Array is guaranteed to be in [order](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach). This is not true of dictionaries. If you want to create a new array, you can simply do something like this:

```
var array2 = array1.map(function(post) {
    return {id: post.id, name: post.name};
});
```